# aurelia router undefined route

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, aurelia

When i do `console.log(router.routes)` I get expected result. A list of all the routes. But when I do `console.log(router.routes[1])` (or any othe index) it returns undefined. What is up with that.
[Image of console in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ESlG.png) and my code

```
activate() {
    console.log(this.router.routes)
    console.log(this.router.routes[1])
}
```

I would like to access every `router.route[i].title` variable but because of this funky javascript I can't manage to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.
Is it possible that you did not define the title for the route?

```
let list = this.theRouter.routes;

for(let i=0;  i<list.length; i++)
{
  let item = list[i];
  console.log(item.title);
}
```